# nswag appends a number suffix to action name for same action names

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, nswag, nswagstudio

I have a ASP.NET Core 6.0 and Angular 13 & TypeScript 4.5 project.

I use Swagger and NSwag for create TypeScript clients.

My swagger.json like as below:

```
 {
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "AdamBadam.Api",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
   "/api/v1/Adam/GetData": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Adam"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AdamListResponse"
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AdamListResponse"
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AdamListResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
   "/api/v1/Badam/GetData": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Badam"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "PageNumber",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "PageSize",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/BadamResponse"
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/BadamResponse"
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/BadamResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

And my nswag config file like as below:

```
{
  "runtime": "Net80",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "fromDocument": {
      "json": "",

      "url": "http://localhost:8080/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
      "output": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToTypeScriptClient": {
      "className": "{controller}HttpService",
      "moduleName": "",
      "namespace": "",
      "typeScriptVersion": 4.5,
      "template": "Angular",
      "promiseType": "Promise",
      "httpClass": "HttpClient",
      "withCredentials": false,
      "useSingletonProvider": false,
      "injectionTokenType": "InjectionToken",
      "rxJsVersion": 6.0,
      "dateTimeType": "Date",
      "nullValue": "Undefined",
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": true,
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "exportTypes": true,
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "exceptionClass": "ApiException",
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "configurationClass": null,
      "useTransformOptionsMethod": false,
      "useTransformResultMethod": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndOperationId",
      "markOptionalProperties": true,
      "generateCloneMethod": false,
      "typeStyle": "Class",
      "enumStyle": "Enum",
      "useLeafType": false,
      "classTypes": [],
      "extendedClasses": [],
      "extensionCode": "",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateTypeCheckFunctions": false,
      "generateConstructorInterface": true,
      "convertConstructorInterfaceData": false,
      "importRequiredTypes": true,
      "useGetBaseUrlMethod": false,
      "baseUrlTokenName": "API_BASE_URL",
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "useAbortSignal": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "includeHttpContext": false,
      "templateDirectory": "templates",
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": "http-services.ts",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  }
}
```

NSwag create two different TypeScript clients. It is good. But NSwag add "2" suffix to BadamHttpService's GetData method.

For example, my clients are like as below:

AdamHttpService.GetData
BadamHttpService.GetData2

If I create another controller that has GetData action, NSwag will create GetData3 method.

Also, I changed **operationGenerationMode** from **MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndOperationId** to **MultipleClientsFromOperationId**, but NSwag create only one client in this situation.

How can I fix it ?